# Flutter: Remove stored values from a page when navigate to

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have a listview builder with a list in the home page and when an item of the list is pressed a second page will open with details of that list. The details are basically another list of cards on each card I have a counter starts ***with zero value***, when user press on each card the counter value will increase.

Now the issue I face is when user go back to home page and then again click on a the same item to go to the second page, they will find the counter values as there were ***(i.e not zeros)***, although I did not include any mechanism to store these values (i.e no sharedpreferance or so).

These values of the counter will not go back to ***zeros***, unless the app is closed and open again.

Is there a way to force the app to reset these values to ***zeros*** as they were originally once the user go back to home page.

This is the code of the listview.builder of the second page:

```
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.cities.attractions.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        widget.cities.attractions[index].localrank++;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Card(
                        child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(widget.cities.attractions[index].name),
                          Center(
                              child: Text(
                                  '${widget.cities.attractions[index].localrank}')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by others. The solution is basically to use the WillPopScope widget to set all "localranks" in widget.cities.attractions to zero when the back button is pressed. For that, we have to define the method in the Widget class and then to use forEach to access each attraction and set the localrank to zero from there.

This is the code:

```
  Future<bool> moveToLastScreen() async {
    setState(() {
       widget.cities.attractions.forEach((attraction) => attraction.localrank = 0);
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => moveToLastScreen(),
      child: Scaffold(...),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to main a list of size equal to no of cards you have on your screen. This can be bool list (List) and initialise the List like

```
int noOfCards; // This variable will have the no of cards on your screen
List<bool> isClicked = new List.filled(noOfCards, false);
```

Now make the value to true when any item is clicked

For Example :- if item on some index is clicked then

```
if(!isClicked[index]){
  isClicked[index] = true;
  // your code to increment the value
}

// navigate to your second page
```

Comment: I did not understand your answer, maybe i did not explain the issue well. Now I have modified the question to make it clearer and added the code of the listview builder for the second page.